# To find minimum and maximum hole of connected component in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How to find minimum and maximum hole in an  image of an connected component analysis. I have done how to find hole: (below code)

```
I = imread('1.jpg');

B=bwlabel(I);

level = graythresh(I);

BW = im2bw(I,level);

numb=bweuler(BW,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

By minimum and maximum hole, I assume that you mean hole with minimum and maximum area.  You can use `regionprops` to find the area of connected components.  But first you have to distinguish holes from background.  So we exclude components that touch the image borders.

```
lbl = bwlabel(~BW);
holes = ~(BW|ismember(lbl,unique([lbl([1 end],:) lbl(:,[1 end])'])));
```

Now you want to find the minimum and maximum area of the components that remain.

```
rp = regionprops(holes);
min_hole_area = min([rp.Area]);
max_hole_area = max([rp.Area]);
```

You didn't say if you wanted just the area or a map of the pixels.  You can get the index of the minimal/maximal hole, but in general it might not be unique.

Comment: I got error when execute the code. the error is Use bwlabel(BW) or double(BW) convert binary image to
a label matrix before calling regionprops.

Comment: You may be using a different version of Matlab than I am.  In any case, just do what it says:  `rp = regionprops(bwlabel(holes));`

Comment: I have to find minimum & maximum size hole in the connected component(CC).when i execute using regionprops(bwlabel(holes)) ,it will print min_hole_area= [],max_hole_area=[],no value will print.

Comment: If you're getting empty results, it suggests that there are no holes in your image.  Is that possible?  Take a look using `imshow(holes)` and `imshow(BW)`.  It might be helpful too if you could post the image you want to work with.